# oracle SQL select from this date_id to this date_id

Tags: sql, database, oracle, query-optimization

I have to display data from a table from year 2011-2014. The table has time id to another table called time which stores the actual year.
I have the statement to select data from this date id to date id.

```
SELECT sum(no_of_placements)
  FROM fact_accounts
 WHERE
  (SELECT account_dim.account_id FROM account_dim WHERE account_dim.account_name = 'DCompany1')
     = fact_accounts.fk2
  AND (
       (SELECT time_dim.time_id FROM time_dim WHERE time_dim.year = 2011)
          = fact_accounts.fk1_time_id
    OR (SELECT time_dim.time_id FROM time_dim WHERE time_dim.year = 2012)
          = fact_accounts.fk1_time_id
    OR (SELECT time_dim.time_id FROM time_dim WHERE time_dim.year = 2013)
          = fact_accounts.fk1_time_id
    OR (SELECT time_dim.time_id FROM time_dim WHERE time_dim.year = 2014)
          = fact_accounts.fk1_time_id
  )
GROUP BY fact_accounts.no_of_placements
```

How do i achieve the same without setting a condition to match `time_id` to each year? This does not seem effective incase there is a larger range of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(no_of_placements)
FROM fact_accounts, account_dim, time_dim 
WHERE account_dim.account_id = fact_accounts.fk2
AND account_dim.account_name = 'DCompany1'  
AND fact_accounts.FK1_TIME_ID = time_dim.time_id
AND time_dim.year BETWEEN 2011 AND 2014

GROUP BY fact_accounts.no_of_placements
```

or

```
SELECT sum(no_of_placements)
    FROM fact_accounts,  
    WHERE
    (select account_dim.account_id FROM account_dim WHERE account_dim.account_name = 'DCompany1') = fact_accounts.fk2

AND fact_accounts.FK1_TIME_ID IN
(select time_dim.time_id from time_dim WHERE 
time_dim.year BETWEEN 2011 AND 2014)

GROUP BY fact_accounts.no_of_placements
```

But why are you both summing by and grouping by no_of_placements?  That makes little sense to me.

Comment: Thank you very much! I first did only group by but it only returned the no_of_placements from only one row and didn't aggregate it. So I used the sum function.